# Wordpress template - How to add class to li tag if submenu exist

Tags: wordpress, class, templates, html-lists, submenu

for example i want create this menu:

```
<div class="menu_wrap">
 <ul class="nav sf-menu">
  <li class="sub-menu"><a href="">Main Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""><span>-</span>Sub Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>-</span>Sub Menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu"><a href="">Main Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href=""><span>-</span>Sub Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><span>-</span>Sub Menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Main Menu 3 without sub menu</a></li>
</ul>
```

how to add class="sub-menu" in li tag(s) that if sub menu is exist:

```
<li class="sub-menu"><a href="">Main Menu 1</a>
```

if not exist echo li without class="sub-menu" :

```
<li><a href="">Main Menu 3 without sub menu</a></li>
```

i have this code for functions.php :

```
//Adds Menus
    add_theme_support( 'menus' );
    register_nav_menus(
            array(
                'mainmenu' => 'The Main Menu'
            )
        );
    function dtuts_main_nav() {
        // display the wp3 menu if available
        wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location'  => 'mainmenu',
            'menu'            => 'mainmenu',
            'container'       => 'div',
            'container_class' => 'menu_wrap',
            'menu_class'      => 'nav sf-menu',
            'echo'            => true,
            'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
            'depth'           => 1,
            'walker'          => new themeslug_walker_nav_menu
        ));
    }
```

i can't write themeslug_walker_nav_menu class please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about WordPress function usage, belongs to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: i'm sorry I did not know,
Thanks for tips

Comment: Please refer the below link. Hope its useful for you http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178263/wordpress-template-how-to-add-class-to-li-tag-if-submenu-exist